# Is there any way to tell what size a bug/fish is after it's in your inventory?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Today's the Bug-Off and according to the advice given [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/120428/160), I should turn my bugs of the same type in ascending order of size.

Unfortunately, I caught all of my bugs last night in preparation, and I didn't realize as I was catching them that I should have written down their sizes in the process.

The only thing I can seem to do is either Release or Show Off outside, neither of which would help me. Inside, I can only Display, and that doesn't seem to give me additional information either.

Is there any way to check the size of a bug (or a fish) after you've already caught it and have it in your inventory? The Encyclopedia only has your record size.

Comment: I don't think so, I haven't found a way thus far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really believe that there is a way to tell the size of each individual bug after you have caught it. I guess that they expect you to remember the size straight after you've caught it. Next time when you're preparing write down all of the bugs you catch and arrange them in your pockets in ascending order before the day of the Bug Off. Sorry that I couldn't be much more help.